# What options are there for dealing with MacBook Pro palm rejection problem?

Tags: trackpad, magic-trackpad

The trackpad in relation to the keyboard on all recent MacBook Pros (at least 2019 on) is either misplaced or too large (or both), creating a lot of palm-rejection problems.

Background: When placing your hands over the keyboard in the standard finger position (fingers on the "a","s","d" and "f" keys on the left hand and "j", "k", "l", ";" on the right hand) the palm covers the right 1/3 of the trackpad. For those who rest their palms of their hands on the laptop while they type, palm-rejection on the trackpad is necessary because the pad below the right thumb will hit the trackpad. palm-rejection will necessarily mis-identify some touches as finger strokes, creating a lot of trackpad noise while typing. (yes, the palm rejection is very good, but there are always going to be plenty of touches that misidentify because everyone is a little different).  The trackpad looks nice, but its placement is impractical (see *Seagram Building*)

**What options are available in software or hardware for altering the palm rejection or blocking the right 1/3 of the trackpad other than a piece of tape?**

Comment: I held off on upgrading my 2012 retina for ages because a least it had a usable trackpad. Now I have a new model; but 8 years of hardware upgrades are barely worth it because of this gimmicky helicopter landing pad (honestly what do people do with these things that justifies this size?). Some googling just found this: https://github.com/cocoahuke/shrink_trackpad. Might give that a try.

Comment: The issue persists after upgrading to 11.2.  I have to physically cover the trackpad with two layers of plastic sandwiching aluminum foil or else I can't type one full line of text without having to reposition the cursor.  Even so I can't entirely eliminate the cursor bouncing around but at least I won't have to scroll every some seconds. Whoever came up with that design AND allow it to be kept that way is just ...

Answer (score 3):

Try turning off “tap to click”. It doesn’t solve palm rejection entirely, but at least your palm will stop clicking elsewhere in the document causing your input to be out of order etc.